# Is there a vertical clock applet?

Tags: gnome-panel, applet, clock

I want to keep my panels down to one, running vertically along the left side of my screen. I'm using the DockBarX applet for launchers and open application access, and have an applet main menu replacement that shows just an icon to save space. However, the date/time isn't customizable, and it shows up sideways. Is there a clock replacement applet that will display the date and time in a vertical format?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the panel itself wider then the clock will adjust and display the time horizontally.  To do this right click on some blank area of the panel and select 'properties', then increase the size to 75 pixels or more and it should realign your clock.

Comment: I know, but the whole point of having a single panel along the left side is to maximize screen real estate. I'm looking for an applet that will display the clock vertically, on several lines (hours one one line, then minutes, then am/pm); I know I've seen it somewhere before, just can't remember where.

Answer (score 0):

There is an XFCE applet that probably (I don't remember 100%, been a while) has this functionality. You would need a wrapper to get it into the gnome-panel though.